# How to compose Angular guard based on NgRX store data

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to create guard which checks wheather route param's value appears on a location list (which is placed in the NgRX store).

The problem is when I filter locations I'm getting only the first result from the stream `locations.length` returns 0 and Observable is closing. Could you please correct me somehow? Locations are probably not yet loaded. I want to wait for them to be loaded to the store and only then check param.

```
canActivateChild(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.locationFacade.locations$.pipe(
      filter(locations => !!locations.length),
      map((locations: Array<Location>) => locations.some(x => x.name === next.params['locationName']))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking on the `length`, I think the better solution would be to introduce a loading state. Something as:

```
canActivateChild(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.locationFacade.locations$.pipe(
      filter(locations => locations.state === 'LOADED'),
      map((locations: Array<Location>) => locations.some(x => x.name === next.params['locationName']))
    );
  }
```